# verifying the complex cosine of a sum formula using exponential definition

Tags: complex-analysis

We know that for complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$ we have the identity:

$\cos(z_1 + z_2) = \cos(z_1)\cos(z_2) - \sin(z_1)\sin(z_2)$.

I want to show that the rhs is the same as the lhs:

$\cos(z_1)\cos(z_2) - \sin(z_1)\sin(z_2) = \frac{e^{iz_1}+e^{-iz_1}}{2i}\frac{e^{iz_2}+e^{-iz_2}}{2i} - \frac{e^{iz_1}-e^{-iz_1}}{2i}\frac{e^{iz_2}-e^{-iz_2}}{2i} = \frac{e^{iz_1}e^{iz_2} + e^{-iz_1}e^{-iz_2} + e^{-iz_1}e^{iz_2} + e^{iz_1}e^{-iz_2}}{-4} - \frac{e^{iz_1}e^{iz_2} + e^{-iz_1}e^{-iz_2} - e^{-iz_1}e^{iz_2} - e^{iz_1}e^{-iz_2}}{-4} = \frac{e^{iz_1}e^{-iz_2} + e^{-iz_1}e^{iz_2}}{-2} = \frac{-i(e^{iz_1}e^{-iz_2} + e^{-iz_1}e^{iz_2})}{2i}$

But here is where I get stuck, because at this point $-i$ will only give me $e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$ which will not help me turn this into $\frac{e^{i(z_1+z_2)} + e^{-i(z_1+z_2)}}{2i}$.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your notion of cosine is wrong.

Comment: @Jonas, I see, there is no i in the denominator for cosine.  That makes a huge difference.

Comment: Right! :) -----